# How to enable Event Scheduler when I open MySQL Server

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with Event Scheduler. It is disabled automatically when I restart the MySQL Server. How can I enable the event scheduler automatically when I restart the MySQL Server.

I have red one solution after a long search, i.e enable the Event Scheduler in `my.ini` file in MySQL with the following command.

```
event_scheduler=on
```

If I make changes in `my.ini` file with the above command it displays an error while saves the `my.ini` file like 'access denied'.

Is there any problem in my above process? If there is, any solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a problem with your privileges in windows and not with mysql, just open the file with notepad which runs with administrator privileges. Right click notepad and chose "run as administrator", then open your my.ini file and edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;  
(or)
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1; // in my.ini or my.cnf file.
```

Then restart your server for the setting to take effect.

Once set 'event_scheduler' will always remain 'ON' no matter whenever your server restarts