# how to change a field automatically in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

how to change a field automatically in phpmyadmin?

```
CREATE EVENT reset
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 MINUTE
        DO
update name_of_table
set name_of_field = 1;
```

Or i have tried.

```
CREATE EVENT myevent 
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 SECOND DO 
UPDATE locationofdriver 
   SET coordinate = 1;
```

Comment: Have you verified that the MySQL event scheduler is enabled?  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'event_scheduler'`

Comment: its off.. how to turn it on

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875797/how-to-enable-event-scheduler-when-i-open-mysql-server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39158933/how-to-check-event-scheduler-status-mysql?s=3|104.7952

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622301/can-i-set-a-mysql-event-schedule-using-phpmyadmin/6622509#6622509